# Exemplo de serviço em Python de metodo Post

Tags: python, web-service, post

Algum exemplo de um serviço de método ´Post´ em Python? Não sei como fazer isso com a ligação à base de dados. Sei como fazer o ´Get´ e deixarei um exemplo abaixo.

```
    @route('/dadosBloqueios', method = "GET")
    def dadosBloqueios():
        response.content_type = 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='*', database='*',
                              user='*', password='*')
        cnx_cursor1 = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)

        dadosBloqueios = { } #lista de dados

####
        sql1 = "SELECT count(*) FROM DB.Utilizadores where Bloqueado = 1;"
        cnx_cursor1.execute(sql1)

        l = cnx_cursor1.fetchone()
        while l is not None:    #vai ler tudo ate o l ser vazio
            dadosBloqueios["Número total de utilizadores bloqueados"] =         l["count(*)"]
            l = cnx_cursor1.fetchone()

        cnx.close()
        return json.dumps(dadosBloqueios)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade é algo bem parecido com o seu exemplo. Você precisa alterar o método para POST e, caso você espere por um conteúdo do tipo **application/json**, poderá ser utilizado o objeto request para recuperar as informações da seguinte maneira:

```
from flask import jsonify, request

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def insert_new():
    json_request = request.get_json() # Recupera o JSON enviado
    # Acessando propriedade json_request["id_time"]

    # Montando retorno da operação, caso seja necessário
    return jsonify({"status": "ok", "obj": obj})
```

Uma vez dentro da operação, para realizar consultas na base de dados você pode seguir da maneira como tem trabalhado no método que recebe o GET.

Comment: E como funciona com a ligação à base de dados? Tem algum exemplo?